# confusion in writing the equation in latex

Tags: latex, overleaf

I'm writing the following formulas in latex and I see the elements of the first equation is spreading in the page. Here is what is what I have tried:

```
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{equation}
\min\limits_{w, \xi_n, \rho} \frac{1}{2} $$ || w || $$^2 + \frac{1}{\gamma n}\biggl(\sum_{i=1}^N \mathbf{\xi}_{i}\biggr) - \rho
\end{equation}
\State subject to:
\begin{equation}
(w \cdot \phi(x_i)) \geq \rho - \mathbf{\xi}_{i}
\end{equation}
```

I appreciate if anyone can help me to fix it.

What I have tried is the following equations

Comment: Please make a compilable [mre] including a class and all packages necessary to compile your code. Which of the algo packages do you use for the `\State` macro?

Answer (score 0):

You can solve removing both the occurrences of `$$` inside your first `equation` environment.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\min\limits_{w, \xi_n, \rho} \frac{1}{2} || w || ^2 + \frac{1}{\gamma n}\biggl(\sum_{i=1}^N \mathbf{\xi}_{i}\biggr) - \rho
\end{equation}

%\State 
subject to:

\begin{equation}
(w \cdot \phi(x_i)) \geq \rho - \mathbf{\xi}_{i}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Also, I commented `\State` in case it is a macro, as in the first comment to your question above.

This way, you get the following output:

[image: screenshot of output]